# What does it mean for a syllogism to be trivial?

Tags: first-order-logic

What does it mean for a syllogism to be trivial?  I am not able to ascertain the definition of "trivial" in relation to a proposition such as A or Not A, not Not A, therefore A.  Is it trivial?  If so, exactly what does "trivial" mean in this context?

Comment: Trivial may simply mean "easy."

Comment: Trivial (in this context) is not being used rigorously. It is being used to mean “obvious”.

Comment: Please, provide the reference where you found it.

Comment: I'm quite sure that it is not a technocal term. It can refer to a self-evident syllogism, like: "All dogs are mammals; all mammals have four legs. Therefore: all dogs have four legs."

Comment: Thank you.  That helps.

Comment: Thank you.  That helps.


The context was this.

A or not A

If the "not A" option is invalidated, we would have
Not not A

But, "not not A" is a double negative which means "A"

So, essentially the argument is A = A which makes it trivial.

I hope I was clear in that.